# Visual Studio version 15.8.1 - can't start iOS simulator for Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

After updated to version 15.8.1, I opened my Xamarin forms project and pair to MAC. MAC is connected. But when I tried to start iOS simulator, it stops at the stage of connecting to MAC. Repeatedly shows "Connecting to MAC", "Checking server" and "Connected".

[image]

Comment: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fandrekraemer.de%2Fblog%2Fxamarin-ios-simulator-stuerzt-mit-fehler-a-fatal-error-occured-when-trying-to-start-the-server-ab%2F&edit-text= Does this link help?

Comment: Demo project in Xcode or Xamarin?

Comment: @jamesfdearborn just check the xcode running or not according to the suggestion from the link you provided. a demo project was created by xcode on MAC. And run it with xcode then the iOS simulator shows. But the problem in Visual Studio 2017 on my windows PC is not solved. When starting Xamarin app with simulator (the simulator from Xamarin), the simulator still stops at the same stage.

Comment: I'll keep looking.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this I ran into the same situation?

Comment: @YuriZolotarev I have downgraded to version 15.7 to avoid this issue.  I raised a bug report to VS team at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/318378/visual-studio-version-1581-cant-start-ios-simulato.html . At this moment, the VS team wants a log file for trouble-shooting (see Alan McGovern's comment in this URL). If your Visual Studio is still with version 15.8.1, can you please provide the log file to VS team? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @yyou I solved my issue like this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52351955/6312077

Comment: @YuriZolotarev Thanks a lot. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the paired Mac
2. Open Activity monitor
3. Kill the mono process highlighted in red
4. Try again

This worked on my end.