# Xamarin IOs simulator doesn't start after Visual Studio Update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have updated Visual Studio to 15.8.4. I code on a PC machine and have a MAC connected via SSH for builds and debuging via the simulator.

Before the simulator would just start up on my MAC. Now a new window comes up on a PC called iOS Simulator which says

Checking server...
Connected...
Checking server... and so on again and again

The connection is established to the MAC and the MAC agent starts successfully. I am even able to deploy the application to the device but when I want to use the simulator this bug occurs.

Has anyone come across this issue? Thanks.

Comment: be sure to login to the Mac, launch XCode, and accept any dialogs that appear

Comment: Well I am logged in, XCode is started, no dialogs come up and actually, I waited for about 10 min and finally the little window on the PC named iOS Simulator told me "Fatal error occured while trying to start the server".

Comment: It looks like it now looking for the simulator somewhere else.... not on the MAC maybe...

Comment: @YuriZolotarev hey, did you solved this issue? i have same now.

Comment: for me restarting and reconnecting everything did the job

Answer (score 2):

Well,

on the windows machine you must go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> IOs settings and disable simulation on a windows machine. For some reason after the VS update this option enabled itself.